# Xamarin TabbedPage + header and footer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

my goal is get page like from image. controlView in top and in the bottom and i the middle tabbed page.

[a image link](https://demo.exposupport.pl/FileManager/image/96572ef233a94d84baba94a0fc1ccb73/Layout/tp_plus.png)

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to create tabbed page that have navigation in bottom?

Comment: I think you will need a CustomRenderer for a TabbedPage

Comment: According to the link, it's not a `TabbedPage` in the middle, it's a `CarouselView`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve anything like that with the out of the box [`TabbedPage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page), as the tabs can only be placed on the bottom of the screen (can't add extra content view between tabs and the edge of the screen).

I would suggest to try the [Sharpnado](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms) so called "pure" tabs. You can read more about these in here https://www.sharpnado.com/pure-xamarin-forms-tabs/. They also have a test app, that shows the capabilities of the [Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms/) nuget.

EDIT: The above nuget also has a CarouselView layout available. [Read more...](https://www.sharpnado.com/carousel-layout-happy-new-horizontallistview/)